# Dropping the definite article before the phrase "surface temperature"

Tags: articles

Why has "the" been left out before the phrase *surface temperature* in the sentence below.(It is from [Crash Course Astronomy#14](https://youtu.be/ZFUgy3crCYY).)

> Venus's thick atmosphere also means (**the**) surface temperature is about the same averywhere on the planet.

It is unclear to me why the speaker has left *the* out becouse it is clear that he was talking about the surface temperature of Venus, not in general about surface temperature.

Comment: Use of an article there is indicated but not necessary. It can be deleted with no loss of comprehension, and so it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "surface temperature" follows so closely behind "Venus" it is clear that that is what surface temperature it is referring to, not surface temperatures in general.

Answer (score 0):

The omission of the definite article in this example is a grammatical error. We're speaking about a specific surface temperature—that of the planet Venus. We'd omit the article only when speaking about "surface temperature" in a general way, e.g., "Surface temperature is commonly measured using a pyrometer."